# How to return TFS workitem fields in WIQL?

Tags: tfs-workitem

I am trying to query workitem info from TFS - specifically from the CMMI Risk template. It looks like no matter what I put in the select clause, I still actually need to look in the Fields collection for the value.  With this query:

```
WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(@"
                                            SELECT [System.Id], 
                                                    [System.WorkItemType], 
                                                    [System.Title], 
                                                    [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity],
                                                    [Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Probability]
                                            FROM WorkItems 
                                            WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'MyProj' 
                                            and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Risk' 
                                            ORDER BY [System.Id] ");
```

I cannot see

```
 queryResults[0].Severity or
 queryResults[0].Probability
```

in the output, but I can see

```
queryResults[0].Fields["Severity"];
```

Seems the select list is irrelevant in this case.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for a few fields properties are created (I believe it are the system fields). For all other fields you need to access it as you described.

So you are not missing anything.

Comment: Yeah I finally saw another post where someone explained that by adding the fields to the select list I am pre-fetching them. If I access them without them being in the select list they are lazy loaded.